# Executing a few commands in bash once an executable closes?

Tags: linux, bash

I have an application that will shut itself down at a specific time, is there a way for a bash script to execute some commands (like move log files, clean temp files) after the application has closed then restart it?

Comment: Best way to do this is with a process supervision system. For instance, `runit` will let you provide a `finish` script to run whenever a supervised process exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to reinvent this wheel, though not at all a good idea.

This can be as simple as:

```
while :; do
  ./run-your-process
  do-some-cleanup
done
```

But really -- don't. Use runit, upstart, daemontools, systemd, supervisord, or one of the many, many other tools which will automate this process for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the main process in your script in the background, you could turn on job control in bash with 'set -bm' and then trap SIGCHLD and do your cleanup and restart in the signal handler.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -bm

childexit() {
   ... cleanup and restart
}

trap 'childexit' SIGCHLD

mainprocess &
```